# How can I catch a Pokemon underwater?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

How can I catch a water-type Pokemon? The Old Man in Cerulean City sold a Magikarp to me, but I already released it.

Answer (score 4):

You can find underwater Pokemon by fishing. To do that you need a rod. There are three fishing rods that are given out throughout the course of each game, and each one is given out by a Fishing Brother.

> - *Old Rod*: Vermilion City (from Fishing Guru)
> - *Good Rod*: Fuchsia City (from Fishing Guru)
> - *Super Rod*: Route 12 (from Silence Bridge Fishing Guru)

Source [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fishing).

Answer (score 3):

Once you reach [Vermilion City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vermilion_City) you can get an Old Rod (and later; [good](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fuchsia_City) and [super](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Route_12#Silence_Bridge) fishing rods) that you can use beside bodies of water to fish for pokemon. Once you beat the Fuchsia City gym, you'll be able to use [Surf](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Surf_(move)#By_HM) outside of battle, and you'll encounter many water-type pokemon while surfing.

Other than that;

- Once you [revive your fossil](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cinnabar_Island) (dome or spiral) the pokemon it
  becomes will be rock/water
- There's someone in the [Silph Co.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Silph_Co.) building who will give you a Lapras
- The Eevee you can get from the [Celadon Condominiums](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celadon_Condominiums) can be evolved with a water stone into Vaporeon